# Isomorphic Symmetric Groups

Tags: group-theory, set-theory, symmetric-groups

Let S(A) be the set of all bijective functions from A ---> A.
Similarly we define S(B).
Then both S(A) and S(B) are groups under function composition.

If S(A) is isomorphic to S(B) , then is it true that |A| = |B| ?

For finite sets this follows immediately.
I ve been stuck to proving ( or disapproving) that this result holds.

My strategy was constructing an injective function from A to B, and then by following symmetry such a function will also exist from B to A as well. Then using F. Bernstein's Theorem, we could conclude that both sets are of equal cardinality.
However, I was not able to do so.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is answered [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12943)

Comment: @user499096 Just to remark the essence of the answers posted in the link suggested above by Derek Holt, the invariant you should be looking at is the *alternate* group on set $A$, namely the subgroup of *even finitary* permutations of $A$. For infinite $A$, $\mathrm{Alt}(A)$ is the *minimum* nontrivial normal subgroup of the full symmetric group $\Sigma(A)$ and it's order is $|\mathrm{Alt}(A)|=|A|$.

Comment: @DerekHolt thanks

Comment: @ΑΘΩ thanks for explaining

Comment: Note that the existence of $A,B$ with $\vert S(A)\vert=\vert S(B)\vert$ but $\vert A\vert<\vert B\vert$ is consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ (this is an immediate consequence of the consistency of $\mathsf{ZFC+2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_1}=\aleph_2}$ for example). So the isomorphism hypothesis is essential.

Comment: A natural follow-up question is whether it holds that for cardinals $\alpha<\beta$, there's no injective homomorphism $S(\beta)\to S(\alpha)$. This indeed holds, although it follows from none of the arguments appearing here. It was proved by de Bruijn in 1957: he even proved that $\mathrm{Alt}(\beta)$ can't be mapped injectively into $S(\alpha)$. *(N. G. de Bruijn, Embedding theorems for infinite groups. Nederl. Akad. Wetensch. Proc. Ser. A. 60 = Indag. Math. 19 1957 560–569.*

Answer (score 4):

Here's an easy self-contained proof. In a group $G$, let $\Xi(G)$ be the set of elements $f$ in $G$ of order 2, such that for every conjugate $g$ of $f$, $fg$ has finite order. The fact that for $X$ infinite, the isomorphism class of $S(X)$ determines $|X|$ immediately follows from:

**Proposition.** Let $X$ be a set and $f$ and element of order $2$ in $S(X)$. Then $f\in\Xi(S(X))$ if and only if $f$ has finite support. In particular, for $X$ infinite $\Xi(S(X))$ has cardinal $|X|$.

Proof: if $f$ has support of finite cardinal $n$, clearly $fg$ has support of cardinal $\le 2n$ and hence has finite order. Otherwise, there exists an injective sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbf{Z}}$ such that $f(x_{2n})=x_{2n+1}$ for all $n\in\mathbf{Z}$. Let $s$ be the permutation such that $s(x_n)=x_{n+1}$ for all $n\in\mathbf{Z}$ (and say identity elsewhere), and $g=sfs^{-1}$. Then $g(x_{2n+1})=x_{2n+2}$ for all $n\ge 0$. Hence $gf(x_{2n})=x_{2n+2}$ for all $n\ge 0$. So $gf$ has infinite order. $\Box$